# How to get element by tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to write JS code to highlight element when user hovers a cursor over it. To achieve it I am trying to add eventListener on every children on first tag "nav" in current document:

```
let navigation = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");
elements = navigation[0].children;

for (element in elements) {
  elements[element].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    event.target.style.color = "#ffbf00";
    event.target.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 20px #ffbf00";
    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.style.color = "";
      event.target.style.textShadow = "0 0 5px #a50068";
    }, 500);
  }, false);
}
```

But when I open it in browser, not only it does not work, but also Chrome says in DevTools that variable "navigation" is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you making sure your script only executes once the DOM is fully parsed? Show where and how you integrate the JS into your HTML.

Comment: A couple hints: You can get the first element by using `querySelector` so you don't have to specify index zero. Of course, you could chain them and avoid `navigation` altogether:  `const navChildren = document.querySelector("nav").children;` Also, you're initializing `elements` as a global variable.

Comment: Why don't you use the `:hover` pseudo class?

Comment: Please provide **feedback** on comments and answers given! Also try to **answer** questions asked with regard to your question.

Comment: `elements[element]` must be just `element` and the loop must be `for...of`, not `for...in`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be more easily accomplished using CSS:

```css
nav>*:hover {
  color: #ffbf00;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #ffbf00;
}
```

As for your JS:

- add `type="module"` or `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tags or your DOM won't be loaded when the script is executed and it won't find your `nav` element.
- you should loop over the items using `for (const element of elements)` (instead of `in`).

Comment: FYI, you don't need the universal selector (`*`) in this case. It's implied.

Comment: You should justify your final point. It needs some explanation.